# WCF service discovery with metadata

Tags: web-services, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-discovery, webservice-discovery

Hi I'm looking for a WCF example which include service discovery and a way to discover/detect the binding type, I think it could be done using metadata exchange
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the correct answer, here are the steps to complete the task:

1. Add a mex endpoint.
2. Add metadata exachange behaviour.
3. in the client application use discovery with metadata criteria.

Discovery with metdatada criteria

```
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
FindCriteria findCriteria =   FindCriteria.CreateMetadataExchangeEndpointCriteria    (ContractType);
    findCriteria.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    findCriteria.MaxResults = 1;// MaxResults;

    FindResponse result = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
    discoveryClient.Close();


    ServiceEndpointCollection eps = MetadataResolver.Resolve(ContractType, result.Endpoints[0].Address);
    return eps[0].Binding;
```